# Synchronizing camel route(s)

Tags: apache-camel

I have multiple routes deployed in a single camel bundle and what I'm trying to achieve is that once a single route starts execution, the other routes should not be executed until the route that got started is finished with execution.

I understand that it is possible to have the whole camelContext encompassing my routes be made single threaded but I see a drawback here in terms of performance.

Has someone had a similar use case and whats the best way to solve this? Since I'm using OSGi Blueprint DSL, any examples will be welcome.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Camel's [Control Bus](http://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html) if you need to control other routes selectively, such as starting and stopping them.

First, you need to prevent the routes you want from executing when your application is started.  This is achieved with autoStartup=false in your route definition:

```
<route id="foo" autoStartup="false">
   <from uri="activemq:queue:special"/>
   <to uri="file://backup"/>
</route>
```

Then at the point in your running route where you want to start another route after doing stuff, simply:

```
<to uri="controlbus:route?routeId=foo&amp;action=start"/>
```

You can also order the startup (and shutdown) of routes, explained in the [Camel documentation here](http://camel.apache.org/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html).